# Which technique should I learn to build personal proxy tool?

Tags: php, proxy

I found this site is just what I need.

http://www.freeingweb.com/

I want to build a personal Poxey tool coz quite a lot of great sites were blocked for me. Which technique should I learn? Is PHP enough for the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a socks proxy ([danted](http://www.inet.no/dante/)) to bypass filtering on remote hosts. Socks allow to use a wide range of protocols, not just only HTTP. This works with any browser without rewriting any of html content, consecutives requests are juste made with the same proxy.

fopen could do the stuff with just php if you can't install anything, but be careful not to allow everyone to connect through, and there is the HTML source rewriting to handle (can be eased with [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A simple proxy could consist of running fopen() on the website, then finding and replacing URI instances of href="...", src="...", url(...), etc. to requests to your website (or else those will link to the target website, not your proxy).